# How to get access to android COM port without NDK

Tags: android, uart

Is it possible to get access to COM port in android without any C code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For COM (serial, UART) ports via USB [dongles](https://www.semiconductorstore.com/pdf/newsite/Roving/Acc-RN-SERIAL-FTD5V-DGL.pdf) based on FTDI ([FT232](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf)), Prolific ([PL2303](http://www.prolific.com.tw/UserFiles/files/ds_pl2303HXD_v1_4_4.pdf)), Silicon Labs ([CP210X](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/CP2102-9.pdf)) and some others, you can use [this](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) library of Felipe Herranz.

FTDI also has [Android Support Page](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm), own libraries [d2xx](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Android_Java_D2XX_2.08.zip) for its devices and even Terminal application example with [source code](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android/J2xx_HyperTerm.zip).

And [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/) platform has "from the box" support of serial port: [UART](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart) with [samples](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback) of using.